# Google Map API - Zoomstart - Catch Zoom Event Before Firing

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, zooming

I need to exclude one zoomlevel. Therefore I need to capture the zoom event, check if I'm going out or in and forward the map to the next legit zoom level.

It seems that the `zoomstart` event isn't working anymore... Any ideas?

Comment: It would be useful to see your code to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: minZoom and maxZoom not doing it for you in Map Options? You just want to exclude a zoom level that's within an acceptable range? I'm having trouble imagining the use case for this. As @duncan mentioned, posting your code will help debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If found a workaround... The trick is to use a global variable. In this case I want to exclude `MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL+1`.

```
var last_zoom_level;
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {

    if(map.zoom == MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL+1) {
        if(last_zoom_level == MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL)
            map.setZoom(MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL+2);
        else if(last_zoom_level >= MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL+2)
            map.setZoom(MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL);
    }

    last_zoom_level = map.getZoom(); }
```